# Missing log for "Failed to reach implicit threshold of 1 sub-policies, required 1 remaining"

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have a docker container with `CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=debug`. However, I never get the output of this debug-block: [/common/policies/implicitmeta.go#L75](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/6c073551a117b8281d676bded20826d2516640ce/common/policies/implicitmeta.go#L75)

I get the `Failed to reach implicit threshold of 1 sub-policies, required 1 remaining` but I'm missing details about which policy is remaining.

`docker logs peer1.org1.example.com --details` also doesn't show the desired information.

How can I influence this behavior?

---

NB: The triggering command is:

`docker exec -w /mnt/docker-shared-mount -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" peer1.org1.example.com peer channel create -o orderer.org1.example.com:7050 -c archive -f /etc/hyperledger/configtx/channel.tx`

Already stopped and wiped all containers beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This information is only available to the orderer. Hence, this command allows me to see the desired debug log:

`docker logs orderer.org1.example.com --details`